# Why the implicit make rule is not working?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a source file `asd.c` and the build in rule for compiling and linking this file is not working for some reason.

Here is my super simple makefile:

```
asd.exe: asd.o
```

I am getting the following errors

```
cc    -c -o asd.o asd.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -c -o asd.o asd.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'asd.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [asd.o] Error 2
```

Comment: do you have the file _aze.c_ (not with an other extension) in the directory containing the makefile/Makefile ? And do you have _cc_ ?

Comment: the makefile and asd.c are in the same dirctory

Comment: And _cc_ ? Is it existing and available through _PATH_ ? just enter _cc_ by hand to check

Comment: Do you do _make_ into the directory containing _asd.c_ or from an other (e.g. `make -f elsewhere/makefile`) ?

Comment: If you do not have `cc` (lowercase) in your search `PATH` or call compiler differently, make sure you export `CC` (uppercase) variable pointing to it as necessary or pass it directly to `make`.

Comment: i am calling make in the same directory and i think i dont have cc, i have mingw

Comment: just enter _cc_ in your shell to know if you have

Comment: 'cc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: ok, that explains (I put possibilities in an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

several possibilities :

- there is no file asd.c in the directory containing the makefile/Makefile
- you do not have *cc* or it cannot be found through PATH. Just enter *cc* by hand in a shell to check
- you start make from an other directory, e.g. `make -f elsewhere/makefile`, in that case *asd.c* cannot be found

---

Note that if you only have the line `asd.exe: asd.o` that will build the executable named `asd.o`

You can change your *makefile* like that :

```
CC = gcc

asd.exe: asd.c
<tab>$(CC) -o asd.exe asd.c
```

Comment: do you mean asd.c?

Comment: ah yes, I have a french keyboard ^^

Comment: set CC to be gcc ?

Comment: put `CC = gcc` in your makefile

Comment: but my makefile is just :asd.exe: asd.o.Putting that there won't help.

Comment: @MartinChekurov It *will* help if you put it before the line you currently have.

Comment: Hmm it worked but how does it work since i am not using the variable CC anywhere?

Comment: @MartinChekurov _make_ uses it implicitely

Answer (score 1):

Your simple makefile should suffice, the most probable thing is that `make(1)` is unable to execute the default rule to compile a `.c` file, the default compiler is named `cc` and to change it to use `gcc` instead, you should change your `Makefile` to this:

```
CC=gcc
asd.exe: asd.o
```

that should work.  You can also create a link to `cc` from `gcc` (that doesn't hurt, and normally `cc` is an alias of `gcc` on sites that have `gcc` installed as the only compiler)

Indeed, you could make `asd` just by saying

```
make asd.exe
```

with no makefile at all, as there's an implicit rule to generate an executable directly from its `.c` source file.  But also you need to specify the compiler if you don't have `cc`, so the command should be:

```
make CC=gcc asd.exe
```

or, if you are going to **always use `gcc`** as your favourite compiler, just create an environment variable `CC` and assign it `gcc` in login environment (I'm assuming you are in Windows ---for the `.exe` extension--- and you know how to include a new environment variable in it)